# Ckeditor Invalid file

Tags: php, ckeditor

Hi Iam using ckeditor for my site , here on clicking browse server ,it list out the folders but on uploading certain file , it rasies an error 'invalid file' , I checked the  ckeditor config(config.php) file for extension and I uploaded the allowed extension ,but the same issue occurs ,also I checked my php.ini whether file_upload was turned 'off' but it is 'on'  , Can anybody help me with this issue please?

Comment: what is the error that you get? please write the error

Comment: The error is ' invalid file' on uploading